# How to run wxGlade generated code

Tags: python, wxglade

I have created my GUI using wxGlade and it looks fine in the display. I am now trying to run the code it generated before adding it to my finished Python program. I have tryed copying it in to the file structure and running it then copying the code into a new file. I have check the files needed are on the pythonpath and they are all. Everytime I get this same error message. Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steb\workspace\Check\GuiAttempt.py", line 85, in <module>
    frame_4 = FirstScreen(None, -1, "")
  File "C:\Users\Steb\workspace\Check\GuiAttempt.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.Title = wxPanel(self, -1, style=wxDOUBLE_BORDER|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 402, in SetTitle
    return _windows_.TopLevelWindow_SetTitle(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.5 (standalone edition) on Wed Mar 28 19:14:57 2012

from wxPython.wx import *

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class FirstScreen(wxFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: FirstScreen.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wxFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.Title = wxPanel(self, -1, style=wxDOUBLE_BORDER|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.label_1 = wxStaticText(self.Title, -1, "LA Task Refactoriser\n", style=wxALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.tree_ctrl_2 = wxTreeCtrl(self, -1, style=wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS|wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT|wxTR_DEFAULT_STYLE|wxSUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.sizer_9_staticbox = wxStaticBox(self, -1, "File A")
        self.tree_ctrl_3 = wxTreeCtrl(self, -1, style=wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS|wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT|wxTR_DEFAULT_STYLE|wxSUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.sizer_10_staticbox = wxStaticBox(self, -1, "File B")
        self.tree_ctrl_4 = wxTreeCtrl(self, -1, style=wxTR_HAS_BUTTONS|wxTR_LINES_AT_ROOT|wxTR_DEFAULT_STYLE|wxSUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.sizer_11_staticbox = wxStaticBox(self, -1, "File C")
        self.button_1 = wxButton(self, -1, "Load Files")
        self.button_2 = wxButton(self, -1, "Quit")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: FirstScreen.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_4")
        self.SetSize((387, 417))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255))
        self.label_1.SetMinSize((160, 38))
        self.label_1.SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255))
        self.label_1.SetFont(wxFont(12, wxROMAN, wxNORMAL, wxBOLD, 0, ""))
        self.label_1.Enable(False)
        self.Title.SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255))
        self.Title.SetForegroundColour(wxColour(0, 0, 255))
        self.Title.SetFont(wxFont(12, wxSCRIPT, wxNORMAL, wxBOLD, 0, ""))
        self.Title.Enable(False)
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: FirstScreen.__do_layout
        sizer_6 = wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)
        sizer_7 = wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)
        sizer_12 = wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_11_staticbox.Lower()
        sizer_11 = wxStaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_11_staticbox, wxHORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_10_staticbox.Lower()
        sizer_10 = wxStaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_10_staticbox, wxHORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_9_staticbox.Lower()
        sizer_9 = wxStaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_9_staticbox, wxHORIZONTAL)
        sizer_8 = wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL)
        sizer_8.Add(self.label_1, 0, wxLEFT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 100)
        self.Title.SetSizer(sizer_8)
        sizer_7.Add(self.Title, 2, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)
        sizer_9.Add(self.tree_ctrl_2, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_7.Add(sizer_9, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_10.Add(self.tree_ctrl_3, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_7.Add(sizer_10, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_11.Add(self.tree_ctrl_4, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_7.Add(sizer_11, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_12.Add(self.button_1, 0, wxLEFT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 75)
        sizer_12.Add(self.button_2, 0, wxLEFT|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 75)
        sizer_7.Add(sizer_12, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        sizer_6.Add(sizer_7, 1, wxEXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_6)
        self.Layout()
        self.SetSize((387, 417))
        # end wxGlade

# end of class FirstScreen
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wxPySimpleApp(0)
    wxInitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_4 = FirstScreen(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_4)
    frame_4.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am using Python 2.7, my IDE is eclipse indigo with PyDev.
Please help.

Comment: I've worked with wx, but I don't know if the code is just... unusual or a little deprecated. wx is easy to use, you might consider writing your (not too complicated) GUI yourself and you end up with more maintainable and less superfluos / redundant code. - The second line, error on line 21, indicates that code generation hasn't worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this:

`self.Title = wxPanel(self, -1, style=wxDOUBLE_BORDER|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL)`

You have named a panel `Title`, but `Title` is a propery that expects a string or unicode.

If you rename `Title` to something else (like `MyTitle`), your code will work.

Do a `Find > Replace` in your favorite editor and change all instances of `self.Title` to `self.MyTitlePanel` (for example) save the file and run it again.

Comment: I noticed that wxGlade uses gettext (packet used for easily localizing), so it might be the case you needed to run gettext.install("FirstScreen") before everything else to have python create the strings for you...

Answer (score 0):

You named one of your inner panels (children of `FirstScreen`) `Title`, so wxGlade tries to assign it to a variable `self.Title`. Incidentally, `self.Title` is a property of `wxFrame` that is used to set the title of the frame, and expects a string as its argument.

To avoid such name clashes, you can prefix your instance variable names with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing to the superb [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/).

With wxGlade I messed around for an hour getting nowhere. Today I tried wxFormBuilder, and had a good working wxPython GUI in less than 30 minutes, complete with events, text boxes, buttons, etc.